# How do I wrap database errors such that I don't expose too much information about the underlying store?

Tags: go

I'm new to Go and wondering how to properly wrap errors after reading https://go.dev/blog/go1.13-errors. I realize this is a subjective question, but I'm looking for any advice on best practices.

I've added code that looks like this in methods in my `store` package (which talks to postgres):

```golang
rows, err := s.db.Query(context.Background(), stmt, ...args)
if err != nil {
    return nil, newStoreError(err)
}

if err := pgxscan.ScanOne(entity, rows); err != nil {
    return nil, newStoreError(err)
}
```

Here is how I've set up the error wrapping:

```golang
package store

func wrapError(err error) error {
    var pgErr *pgconn.PgError
    if errors.As(err, &pgErr) {
        if pgErr.Code == "23505" {
            return fmt.Errorf("record already exists")
        } else {
            return fmt.Errorf("unknown error")
        }
    } else {
        return fmt.Errorf("unknown error")
    }
}

func newStoreError(err error) error {
    return wrapError(err)
}
```

My plan is to handle the common postgres error codes I get back from the database driver and add a message that doesn't reveal too much information.

Is there a more idiomatic way that you can suggest, or is this way in-line with what the link I posted suggests?

Comment: What's interesting is that Dave Cheney [advocated](https://dave.cheney.net/2016/06/12/stack-traces-and-the-errors-package) for wrapping pretty much every error, in the interest of producing a usable stack trace, in 2016; and that advice seems to be more common than the advice in the 2019 article you linked to (which is also "official" Go communication). In practice, I tend to see people err on the side of wrapping. Use of `.Is()` is still pretty uncommon in my experience... custom error types and typecasting, like you're doing with `pgErr`, is still popular.

Comment: For your use case, consider what's more useful: a `store` package that doesn't expose its internal details, or informative stack traces when errors do happen? Perhaps there's a way to get both that I don't know of. In practice, though, I can tell you that Kubernetes wraps most of its errors and exposes all sorts of inner details... but that's necessary often to find the root cause.

Comment: Thanks for the response @RobertNubel. In my case, my flow is `api` package/layer that calls out to `service` biz logic layer that calls out to `store` layer. I want to return errors that don't expose too much information, but the `store` layer could eventually log the actual low level/internal error (sorry for my terminologies). For example, I don't want the consumer to know which unique constraint on which table, etc. information. Only that the record already exists. Do you think it makes sense in that context? Thanks!

Comment: In my personal opinion, I'd suggest your `store` package return "sentinel" errors like `store.RecordAlreadyExists` that wrap the lower-level errors . Yes, you run the risk that someone could write code using those details inappropriately, like `if err.Is(sql.ErrNowRows)`, but I think it should be obvious that checking `Is` for errors in a different package than the one you're invoking is a risky proposition.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are worried about a case when your API server returns a database-related error with sensitive details to the API clients.

If this is the case, I recommend defining your own type of errors and hooking into your API framework to make errors of this type the only ones returned as-is to the users. If an error of another type is received by the framework, log the error and return a general error instead.

For example, defining a UserFacingError struct:

```golang
package userfacingerrors

type UserFacingError struct {
    message       string
    originalError error
}

func (u UserFacingError) Error() string {
    return u.message
}

func (u UserFacingError) Unwrap() error {
    return u.originalError
}

func Wrap(err error) error {
    return UserFacingError{originalError: err, message: err.Error()}
}
```

And wherever you do want the error message to be returned to the user, return a `UserFacingError` or wrap the original error with it.

Then, find in the API framework's docs how you hook into its error-handling process, almost all frameworks have their way to do so. In there, put a code that replaces non-UserFacingErrors with some general error. For example:

```golang
func ErrorHandler(err error) error {
    var userErr UserFacingError
    if errors.As(err, &userErr) {
        return userErr
    }
    log.Printf("A internal error occured: %v\n", err)
    return errors.New("internal server error")
}
```

This way your API is secure-by-default, and the only errors that are explicitly meant for users will be visible to them.

I actually wrote a [blog post](https://otterize.com/blog/who-moved-my-error-codes) a few months ago about a similar problem I had with [gqlgen's](https://github.com/99designs/gqlgen) GraphQL server, and how I both masked sensitive error messages and added error types there. In that case, the way to integrate with the GraphQL server error handling was to implement the `GqlErrorPresenter()` function. You can check the blog post and the [example project](https://github.com/otterize/graphql-error-codes-example) for more details.